# While I do a commit in SVN I get an error

Tags: svn

When I try to commit a File in SVN using eclipse i get the following error

```
  Path is not a working copy directory
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

My workspace: c:\my_workspace\

My project is in: c:\my_workspace\project1

project1 is a checked out project from the same SVN

Comment: How did you create the project directory?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

From a console, in the base project folder I used the following commands:

```
svn resolve --accept working .
```

That didn't seem to fix Eclipse though.  But I could then do:

```
svn revert .
```

and it all started being recognised in Eclipse again.

Apparently it's quite easy to do by accident in Eclipse - mine happened by a bad drag/drop from an svn:ignored folder to a SVN folder in Eclipse's file manager which I tried to cancel half-way through.

Answer (score 0):

call svn commit from withing the working directory...

`c:/my_workspace/project1>svn commit`

Comment: I don want to commit the entire project. I just want to commit a single file

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your project into the Subversion repository. The message you get means that the directory is not connected to the repository in any way.

Comment: Actually itz a checked out project from SVN

Comment: It cannot be, at least not as far as Subversion is concerned. As @odez213 pointed out, it is possible that your metadata got corrupted. Look in the directory in question: Is there a `.svn` folder? Does it contain proper values?

Answer (score 0):

Your .svn metadata folder might have been corrupted/deleted hence the svn not being able to recognize it. You may need to recreate your folder structure by making a clean checkout from your project.